# Why does qjsonvalue todouble conversion cause data loss?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore

QJsonValue toDouble() conversion generates wrong values causing data loss.

```
QJsonObject obj;
obj.insert("dbl",double(73183493944884961));


double d = obj.value("dbl").toDouble();
qulonglong ul = d;
qulonglong ul2 = 73183493944884961;

qDebug ()  << ul << ul2;
```

Output:

```
73183493944884960 73183493944884961
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toDouble() means it returns a double (that you cast to qulonglong then) which is inherently a precision loss. You can easily figure this out without involving json into this, by printing out this:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QDebug>

    int main()
    {
        qulonglong ul2 = double(73183493944884961);
        qDebug() << ul2;
        return 0;
    }
```

#### Building (something similar)

```
g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -lQt5Core main.cpp && ./a.out
```

#### Output

```
73183493944884960
```

Comment: @Ashish: try 145241087982812481.

Comment: @Ashish: QString QString::number(double n, char format = 'g', int precision = 6) [static]

Comment: Why did you think you could do that? It is not related to Qt, if you try to cast it that way in C/C++, you inherently lose precision. See the example above. Also, you could simply store then the value as string as well.