# Why is there a precision loss in QJsonValue::toDouble?

Tags: c++, json, qt

I would like to store a `double` value in [`QJsonObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html) and retrieve the same value later. However, the retrieved value is with lower precision.

Here is an example:

```
qDebug() << QJsonObject({{"number", 49.195502187}}).value("number").toDouble();
```

outputs `49.1955`, instead of `49.195502187`.

I have checked [Why does qjsonvalue todouble conversion cause data loss?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19207264/5366641), but it is about conversion between data types and not relevant to my specific case.

How to retrieve the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <QtCore>

int main() {  
   auto const value = 49.195502187;
   auto const recovered = QJsonObject({{"number", value}}).value("number").toDouble();
   Q_ASSERT(value == recovered);
}
```

Works for me. There's no precision loss. Generally speaking, code speaks better than words, so if you're saying that something happens, you better write a test case with an assertion to that effect, and only post the question if the assertion proves a problem. It also makes it very clear what your expectations are - there's no ambiguity in the code, as there would be in English (as long as you don't depend on undefined or implementation-defined behavior, that is).

Answer (score 7):

## Cause

The precision loss occurs only when the value is displayed. Internally the correct value is stored. To make sure it is like that, break the code down like this:

```
QJsonObject json({{"number", 49.195502187}});
double value = json.value("number").toDouble();

qDebug() << value;
```

Then use a debugger with a breakpoint set at `qDebug() << value;`:

[image]

## Solution

I would suggest you to use [`QString::number`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-6) in order to set the desired precision for the displayed value, e.g.:

```
qDebug() << QString::number(value, 'g', 14);
```

This will give you the value you have stored in the JSON:

```
49.195502187
```